# Cambia la primera letra de cada palabra a mayúscula y el resto en minúscula

Tags: c, array

Actualmente, puedo convertir la primera letra a partir de la segunda palabra, pero no logro hacer que a partir de la primera palabra se convierta la letra, este es lo que tengo ♥

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int relleno;
char texto[251];

printf("Introduzca una cadena -> " );

gets(texto);

for(relleno=0; texto[relleno]!='\0' ; relleno++)
{
    if(texto[relleno-1]==' ')
    {
        texto[relleno] = toupper(texto[relleno]);
    }
    else
    {
        texto[relleno] = tolower(texto[relleno]);
    }
}
    printf(" %s ",texto);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aparte de la excelente [respuesta de Saul](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/189910/2742) me gustaría aportar una aproximación diferente que no implica el uso de [banderas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag).

Podríamos [tokenizar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analizador_l%C3%A9xico) el texto y por cada token aplicar una transformación consistente en pasar a mayúscula el primer símbolo y a minúscula los restantes:

```
char texto[251] = {0};
fgets(texto, 250, stdin);

for (char *palabra = strtok(texto, " "); palabra; palabra = strtok(NULL, " "))
{
    for (int i = 0; palabra[i]; ++i)
        printf("%c", i ? tolower(palabra[i]) : toupper(palabra[i]));
    printf(" ");
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando <kbd>[Aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Yover8V38eItHQs0)</kbd>.

Comment: Me gusta la idea, aunque es una lastima que strtok_s() de C11 aún no esté mayormente implementada en los compiladores para poder hacer este tipo de operaciones en paralelo (Aunque existe la versión Posix: strok_r()). Por cierto, fgets() maneja automáticamente el carácter nulo así que no es necesario reducir 1 a la longitud; con fgets(texto, 251, stdin); basta.

Answer (score 5):

Una tercera posiblidad. Sin utilizar flags:

```
int main()
{
  char texto[251];

  printf("Introduzca una cadena -> " );
  gets(texto);

  char* ptr = texto;

  while( *ptr != '\0' )
  {
    while( !isalpha(*ptr) && (*ptr != '\0') )
      ptr++;

    if( isalpha(*ptr) )
    {
      if( *ptr >= 'a' )
        *ptr = toupper(*ptr);
      ptr++;
    }

    while( isalpha(*ptr) )
    {
      *ptr = tolower(*ptr);
      ptr++;
    }
  }

  puts(texto);
}
```

El funcionamiento es simple:

- El primer bucle se reptie hasta que alcanzamos el final de la cadena.
- Dentro de dicho bucle:

  - Mientras no encontremos una letra, se descartan los caracteres.
  - Si el caracter es una letra (hemos podido llegar tambien al final de la cadena), se pone a mayúsculas.
  - Mientras encontremos más letras (ya hemos puesto a mayúsculas la primera), estas letras se ponen a minúsculas.

Así, ante una secuencia, por ejemplo:

```
teXTo##  ##dE    pRuebA
```

`ptr` empieza apuntando a la primera letra, la `t`. Como es una letra se pone a mayúsculas:

```
TeXTo##  ##dE    pRuebA
^
```

A continuación, se ponen a minúsculas el resto de letras:

```
Texto##  ##dE    pRuebA
     ^
```

Segunda iteración del bucle, lo primero que hacemos es descartar los separadores:

```
Texto##  ##dE    pRuebA
           ^
```

Ahora, como el caracter apuntado es una letra la ponemos a mayúsculas:

```
Texto##  ##DE    pRuebA
            ^
```

Las letras que siguen se ponen a minúsculas:

```
Texto##  ##De    pRuebA
             ^
```

Tercera iteración, se descartan los separadores:

```
Texto##  ##De    pRuebA
                 ^
```

El caracter es una letra, a mayúsculas:

```
Texto##  ##De    PRuebA
                  ^
```

Se vuelven a poner las letras siguientes en minúsculas.

```
Texto##  ##De    Prueba
                       ^
```

Como hemos alcanzado el final de la cadena, el algoritmo se detiene.

Answer (score 4):

Actualmente la estrategia que usas para determinar el inicio de una palabra es comprobar que el carácter justo anterior sea un espacio, lo cual funciona para la mayoría de las partes de una oración excepto para la primera palabra, pues esta no tiene ningún texto antes.
Por ejemplo, en la frase "Una frase de ejemplo":

```
Una frase de ejemplo
^   ^     ^  ^
|   |     |  |
|   |     |  +-- La palabra "ejemplo" tiene un espacio justo antes
|   |     |
|   |     +-- La palabra "de" tiene un espacio justo antes
|   |
|   +-- La palabra "frase" tiene un espacio justo antes
|
+-- La palabra "Una" NO tiene un espacio justo antes
```

Una estrategia común en estos casos es usar una variable booleana (que puede valer cierto o falso) auxiliar durante el recorrido que indique si se está actualmente dentro de una palabra. Dicha variable empezaría en "falso", y si encuentra cualquier carácter que no sea un espacio su valor pasaría a ser "verdadero" para simbolizar que se entró en una palabra. Asimismo la variable debería regresar a falso si encuentra un espacio.
El código sería algo así:

```
bool dentro_de_palabra = false; // Al principio está fuera
for (relleno = 0; texto[relleno] != '\0'; relleno++)
{
    if (texto[relleno] == ' ')
    {
        dentro_de_palabra = false; // Fuera de palabra
    }
    else
    {
        dentro_de_palabra = true; // Dentro de palabra
    }
}
```

Sin embargo no basta con saber si estamos dentro o fuera de una palabra. Necesitamos saber el momento exacto en que ingresamos en una palabra dado que el else solo maneja que estemos dentro de la palabra, sin importar si es al inicio/medio o final de la misma.
Podemos añadir dentro del else una comprobación que pregunte si ya estábamos dentro de una palabra previamente o no, para así capturar el momento exacto en que ingresamos en una nueva palabra:

```
bool dentro_de_palabra = false; // Al principio está fuera
for (relleno = 0; texto[relleno] != '\0'; relleno++)
{
    if (texto[relleno] == ' ')
    {
        dentro_de_palabra = false; // Fuera de palabra
    }
    else
    {
        if (dentro_de_palabra)
        {
            // Ya estábamos dentro de una palabra
        }
        else
        {
            // Acabamos de entrar en una nueva palabra
            dentro_de_palabra = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora solo falta hacer las operaciones correspondientes. Cada vez que se ingrese a la posición de una palabra hay que convertir la letra en mayúscula y en caso contrario hay que convertirla en minúscula.
También puede convenir usar la función isspace() en lugar de igualar con ' ' dado que dicha función también toma en cuenta otros caracteres como la tabulación (\t).
El código se vería algo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char texto[251];

    printf("Introduzca una cadena -> " );
    fgets(texto, 251, stdin); // Lee 251 caracteres desde el teclado (stdin)
                              // La función gets() puede leer más de la cuenta

    bool dentro_de_palabra = false; // Al principio está fuera
    for (int relleno = 0; texto[relleno] != '\0'; relleno++)
    {
        if (texto[relleno] == ' ')
        {
            dentro_de_palabra = false; // Fuera de palabra
        }
        else
        {
            if (dentro_de_palabra)
            {
                // Ya estábamos dentro de una palabra
                texto[relleno] = tolower(texto[relleno]);
            }
            else
            {
                // Acabamos de entrar en una nueva palabra
                dentro_de_palabra = true;
                texto[relleno] = toupper(texto[relleno]);
            }
        }
    }

    printf(" %s ",texto);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "No siempre,se respetan los. Espacios entre signos de puntuación; estas;palabras; ¿cuentan como palabras? ... y las 'comillas' ¡eso sí que son otro tema!" =P

Comment: @aloMalbarez Tienes razón, supongo que lo que se considera aquí serian mas bien bloques de texto.